# VBScript to create tree from Array of lines

Tags: arraylist, vbscript, tree

I have an array with list of strings like this:

```
1=xItem
2=xInstance
3=xVersion
4=xValue
2=pInstance
3=pVersion
1=yItem
2=yInstance
2=zInstance
3=zVersion
4=zValue
```

I have an class definition like this:

```
Class InfoEntry
    Public Name
    Public infoList
    Private Sub Class_Initialize()
        set infoList= CreateObject("System.Collections.ArrayList")
    End Sub
End Class
```

I want to have tree structure like this:

```
Root
-xItem
    -xInstance
        -xVersion
            -xValue
    -pInstance
        -pVersion
-yItem
    -yInstance
    -zInstance
        -zVersion
            -zValue
```

initial requirement was only upto two levels. But now the depth may vary.

I have written logic as below which only works for two levels in depth. I can put my code here if it is needed. But its huze. I want to have much better version. I am sorry I am not good at VBscript.

I am not good at VBScript, so trying to find the logic in VB.

```
     Function GetTree(NodeName,FileLines,counter)
        Call WriteToLog(LOG_AL_NIINFO, "started creating Tree structure for Node " & NodeName, False)
        Dim OEntry
        Set OEntry = New InfoEntry
        OEntry.Name=NodeName
        Dim StringTree,Stack
        set StringTree = CreateObject( "System.Collections.ArrayList")  
        set Stack = CreateObject( "System.Collections.ArrayList")
        dim i,curr
        For i=0 To (FileLines.Count-1)
            set curr=FileLines(i)
            call Stack.Add(curr)
            if (i+1) < (FileLines.Count-1) then
             if InStr(FileLines(i+1),counter & "=") = 1 then
                call StringTree.Add(Stack)
                set Stack= CreateObject( "System.Collections.ArrayList")
            end if
            end if
        Next
         StringTree.Add(Stack)   

        If StringTree.Count > 0 Then
            For Each collection in StringTree
                If collection.Count > 0 Then
                    dim TopNode
                    set TopNode=collection(0)
                    call collection.Remove(TopNode)
                    dim splitKey,rootKey
                    set splitKey=Split(TopNode,"=")
                    rootKey=splitKey(1)
                    call OEntry.infoList.Add(GetTree(rootKey,collection,(counter+1)))
                End if
            Next
        End If
        Call WriteToLog(LOG_AL_NIINFO, "Finsihed creating Tree structure for Node " & NodeName, False)

        if VMS_GCO_Structure.Exists(NodeName) = false And OEntry.infoList.Count <> 0  then
            call VMS_GCO_Structure.Add(NodeName,OEntry)
        end if
        GetTree=OEntry      
end function
```

I am getting null reference error with this. Can someone suggest me where i am doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

I found an answer myself which is perfectly working. I hope it will help for others

```
Class InfoEntry
        Public Name
        Public isValid
        Public infoList
        Public childList
        Public Sub Class_Initialize()
            isValid = False
            set infoList = CreateObject("System.Collections.ArrayList")
            set childList = CreateObject("System.Collections.ArrayList")
        End Sub
    End Class



Function GetTree(nodeName, fileLines, counter)
       ' Call WriteToLog(LOG_AL_NIINFO, "Indexing Tree structure for " & nodeName, False)
        Dim oEntry
        set oEntry = New InfoEntry
        oEntry.Name = nodeName
        Dim stringTree, stack
        set stringTree = CreateObject("System.Collections.ArrayList")
        set stack = CreateObject("System.Collections.ArrayList")
        Dim i, j, curr
        i = 0
        j = FileLines.Count
        Do While i < j
             curr = FileLines.Item(i)
            Call stack.Add(curr)
            If (i + 1) < j Then
                If InStr(FileLines(i + 1), counter & "=") = 1 Then
                    Call stringTree.Add(stack.Clone())
                    set stack = CreateObject("System.Collections.ArrayList")
                End If
            End If
            i = i + 1
        Loop
        Call stringTree.Add(stack.Clone())
        Dim topNode
        i = 0
        j = stringTree.Count
        Do While i < j
            If stringTree.Item(i).Count > 0 Then
                topNode = stringTree.Item(i).Item(0)
                Call stringTree.Item(i).Remove(topNode)
                Dim splitKey, rootKey
                splitKey = Split(topNode, "=")
                rootKey = splitKey(1)
                Call oEntry.infoList.Add(rootKey)
                Call oEntry.childList.Add(GetTree(rootKey, stringTree.Item(i), (counter + 1)))
            End If
            i = i + 1
        Loop
        set GetTree = oEntry
    End Function
```

Comment: the two arraylist inside the class are meant for other puposes which script has to do..

Answer (score 0):

The depth is already indicated by your string. The following method does away with trees and nodes and so on and can be written using simple VBScript statements and no additional data structures. It also works for arbitrary depth.

- find location of = in each string
- extract the substring before it
- convert it to integer and multiply with 4
- output that many spaces
- extract substring after =
- output a - and the second substring